# How do I remove the strange field below the formula field?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I am experiencing the following, when I open any Excel file (*.xlsx extension, no macros/vba).

[image]

See the arrows...
I want to remove the strange ugly field, on which I have drawn the arrows with paint.

Any idea how to remove it?

Any idea why it appeared there?

Comment: the right arrow shows the formula bar, you can resize it (https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2016/01/21/formula-bar-excel/)

Comment: @MátéJuhász - in the screenshot the formula bar it is already resized. It does not matter whether I resize it or not, the problem with the field below the formula bar stays.

Comment: What version are you using? You say it happens when you "*open any Excel file*". Does that include creating a new file? What view are you in (normal, layout, page break)? Are you using objects in column C; it looks like there is a text box in that column (white over the green cell color)?

Comment: @CharlieRB - I use only Office 2010. Not when I create a new file. There is nothing specific for column `C`, simply the colleague with the screenshot had some text inside and I have decided to delete it in paint, before publishing it. Normal View.

Comment: Are these shared documents open and saved by others? Are they stored in a network location? Anyone else manipulating them with an add-on of some sort?

Comment: No Addin. No VBA. No macros. Were shared, but when the screenshot was taken, they were saved on a desktop.

Comment: Are all people seeing the same thing? What happens if you copy the data to a new file and save it?

Comment: @CharlieRB - only one person sees this kind of issue. Saved & opened and the issue is seen again.

Comment: Since it is only one person seeing it, you may want to try a repair install, or uninstall and reinstall, of Office for that one person.

Comment: @CharlieRB - indeed, it is one. But I thought that it is quite strange and there could be another way, just to avoid the reinstall.

Comment: Understood. In some cases, programs get corrupted and act in ways that cannot be explained. Reinstalling will often resolve those issues.